# Is it possible to render an object on one screen only with google-vr?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

Using google-vr and unity, I would like to display certain objects on one view/screen/eye only. So that object would be visible on one eye and not on the other. Is that possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Layers

- For your object, set its Layer to "Water" (as an example)
- Select "Main Camera Right"
- From Culling Mask drop-down, disable "Water" layer (now this camera won't see any objects on that layer)

More info:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html